# mysql server password change while restoring

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, mysqldump, restore, authentication

I restored all database backup from another server's dumpfile to my machine. At the end my mysql server's password changed to that mysql server's password. Why it got overwritten? What i need to do to prevent this?
Thanks & Regards,
Praveen.

Comment: can you please give the command which you have used in creating dump and then restoring it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me you have also dumped the ***mysql***  database which contains the users privileges in the **users table** of mysql database.  & one more-thing you may have used `--add-drop-database`  or `--add-drop-table` while generating the dump

i.e     `mysqldump -u user -p passwordd --add-drop-database  --all-databases > /home/dump.sql`

and when you have restored it on your local machine as your dump contains the 
drop table statements.so it had firstly dropped your **user table** in mysql database and then restored new one from the dump thats why you are facing the problem. so don't include the mysql database while generating the dump.

please see various option of **mysqldump**  using `mysqldump --help`.

Thanks....